# NSolve failing to find the roots of an transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

Why `NSolve` is not working for this problem. By plotting the determinant equation it is clear that there are roots between 5 t0 10, but `NSolve` could not able to find it.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

L = 4;
W = a[1]*Sin[b*x] + a[2]*Cos[b*x] + a[3]*Sinh[b*x] + a[4]*Cosh[b*x];

e[1] = D[W, {x, 2}] /. x -> 0
e[2] = D[W, {x, 3}] /. x -> 0
e[3] = W /. x -> L
e[4] = D[W, {x, 1}] /. x -> L

var = Table[a[i], {i, 1, 4}];
eq = Table[e[i], {i, 1, 4}];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
P = Det[R]
Plot[P, {b, 0, 5}]
s1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < b < 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

L = 4;
W = a[1]*Sin[b*x] + a[2]*Cos[b*x] + a[3]*Sinh[b*x] + a[4]*Cosh[b*x];

e[1] = D[W, {x, 2}] /. x -> 0;
e[2] = D[W, {x, 3}] /. x -> 0;
e[3] = W /. x -> L;
e[4] = D[W, {x, 1}] /. x -> L;

var = Array[a, 4];
eq = e /@ Range[4];
R = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];

P = Det[R] // FullSimplify;
```

The exact solutions are [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) functions

```
s1 = Solve[P == 0 && 0 < b < 10]
```

[image]

Alternatively, to use NSolve don't use machine precision

```
s1n = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < b < 10,
   WorkingPrecision -> 15];

(b /. s1) == (b /. s1n)

(* True *)

Plot[P, {b, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> {-.1, .1},
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{b, 0} /. s1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: If I want to get the values of the coefficients  `a[i]` in the equation `W`, I need to substitute the value of `b` in matrix `R` and solve for the nullspace which eventually leads to `a[i]` right? But how to have general symbolic values for coefficients a[i] such that if I substitute any `nth` root of `b` should give me the expression `W`.

Comment: You should post your follow-up question as it is not just a clarification of the original "Why NSolve is not working?"